# Cannot reference class in Java Code

Tags: java, class, path

I have a problem compiling a code for an university lecture.

There is the file Test. java given and may not be changed:

```
package sorting;
import java.util.*;

class Test {

static final int BOUND_RANDOM = 99;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("n = ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    Random random = new Random(123);
    Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; ++i) {
        // 1. Parameter = x-Koordinate linke untere Ecke
        // 2. Parameter = y-Koordinate linke untere Ecke
        // 3. Parameter = Breite
        // 4. Parameter = Hoehe
        rectangles[i] = new Rectangle(random.nextInt( BOUND_RANDOM),
                                      random.nextInt( BOUND_RANDOM),
                                      random.nextInt( BOUND_RANDOM) + 1,
                                      random.nextInt( BOUND_RANDOM) + 1);
    }
    System.out.print("Vor Sortieren:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rectangles));
    // long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    SortingAlgos.selectionSort(rectangles);
    // SortingAlgos.insertionSort(rectangles);
    // Arrays.sort(rectangles);

    // long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //System.out.println("Benoetigte Zeit: " + (end - start) + " Millisekunden");
    System.out.println("Nach Sortieren:");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rectangles));
}

}
```

Next I wrote a file in which I define the class Rectangle, saved in the same folder. I create a Constructor, based on the call in Test.java and I save and compile the file in the same folder as Test.java:

```
package sorting;
public class Rectangle{

int x,y,width, height;


public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height){
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
this.width=width;
this.height=height;
}


public String toString(){
return "x="+this.x;
}


}
```

Can anyone give me a quick shot, of where am I going wrong?

PS: The problem is I get an error while compiling Test.java where class Rectangle is a not found symbol. I also got this error in Linux and Win 10.

Comment: Use an IDE for starters.

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: hehe, yeah I would have, but usually I am programming in R and Python and these 2 go uncombined in IDE's, therefor I am inconclusive of what to use (Start the haggle with IntelliJ or go down Eclipse)

Comment: Test.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[n];
        ^
  symbol:   class Rectangle
  location: class Test
Test.java:13: error: cannot find symbol

Comment: is your Rectangle class has `package sorting;` same as Test class? and is "same folder" you are talking about is `sorting`? also traditionally in Java classes are `public class ...` e.g. `public class Rectangle` , `public class Test` and so on.

Comment: If the reason you aren't using an IDE is only because you are indecisive which one to use my tipp would be: Flip a coin or roll a dice to make the decision. Because any IDE is better than no IDE.

Comment: @Oh GOD SPIDERS: Sry but I do not agree.

Comment: @Vadim: I did declare now as public, did not change the error for sure

Comment: @Nuke How are you compiling? Also, *why* not use an IDE? Almost every professional dev uses an IDE, you should start learning to use one..

Comment: @xtratic :I am compiling javac Rectangle.java -> class Rectangle gets created, then I am compiling javac Test.java -> error pops up.
I wouldn't say I am not using an IDE, I am just not using one atm. I worked with Eclipse, and had good experience, but something tells me I should change to IntelliJ soon, but last time I tried it was very difficult to start with, so I postpone

Comment: @Nuke there's your problem.. should've used an IDE

Comment: @Nuke : btw  from where you are getting SortingAlgos class? I cant see any imports for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the directory with your sources:

run `javac Test.java Rectangle.java` or just `javac *.java`

Your classes need to know about each other. `Rectangle` has no dependencies on outside classes, so it compiles fine on its own. But `Test` depends on `Rectangle` but doesn't know about the class, so compiling them together will fix this.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be it. Thank you very much and sorry everyone for the delay

Answer (score 2):

The Test class in under package 'sorting'. Your class Rectangle also should be under package 'sorting'

You need to put the classes in folder called as `sorting`. Then go a one level up and then compile your classes from there.

```
javac sorting/Rectangle.java
javac sorting/Test.java
```

Comment: added line package sorting; to the file containing class Rectangle, still same error

Comment: You need to compile Rectangle.java first

Comment: I did so and class Rectangle in same folder gets created just fine.

Comment: Oh does maybe the class path change after importing this package sorting? Do I need to reset or something?

Comment: Have you tried to compile this? Does it work for you? Maybe is my system or something